# SUMO mobility model

Tags: sumo, mobility

By default, SUMO used the Krauss Car-following model, is it possible to change the parameter, and how? Secondly, how can I also change from the default car-following to the lane-changing model in SUMO? Thank you in anticipation of your answer.

Comment: Is SUMO a [software tools commonly used by programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the car following model or adapting the parameters can be done by defining a new vehicle type such as

```
<vType id="idmAlternative" minGap="2" carFollowModel="IDM" tau="1.0" />
```

see https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Definition_of_Vehicles%2C_Vehicle_Types%2C_and_Routes.html#car-following_models

The lane change model is independent of the car following model so there is always a car following *and* a lane changing model active. also the lane changing model parameters are described on the page https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Definition_of_Vehicles%2C_Vehicle_Types%2C_and_Routes.html#lane-changing_models

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I'm grateful.